# Using grep with regex

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to extract from my exim_mainlog all email subject which are in this format

```
T="any possible chars here"
```

using my Centos 6 console.

I am not expert with regex , I am using this command

```
# grep -E -io " T=\"[ A-Za-z0-9-]*+[\s\S]\"" exim_mainlog
```

however it returns only 10% of all results , for example results like this

```
T="Welcome to \"My Concepts Support\""
T="[ TEST ] Do you want play ?"
T="{ another@test! }"
```

are not returned . How to do to return all T="*" results from my 
exim_mainlog ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's easier to specify what characters you don't want:

```
T="[^"]*"
```

This matches `T="` followed by anything that isn't a `"`, then a final `"`.

However, I note that in your extended example, you have embedded escaped quotes. If you want to match them as well, you'll need something along the lines of:

```
T="([^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

This matches:

```
T="       # as expected
(         # either...
   [^"\\] #   not a " or a \
|         # or
   \\.    #   a \ followed by anything
)
*         # as many times as you want
"         # then the final quote
```

The final command is then:

```
grep -Eo 'T="([^"\\]|\\.)*"' exim_mainlog
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
grep -E -o '^T=\"(.*)\"$' exim_mainlog
```

Above assumes that there's nothing more in a line (`^` and `$` anchors) other than your text.

Like for example:

```
T="Something i$ h3r3 "^#^*# and h3h3"
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -P (PCRE)` can be helpful here:

```
grep -Pio ' T=".*?(?!((.*?"){2})*[^"]*$)"' file
```

Which basically matches `"` after even # of matches.